# Request response is being stored as bool

Tags: php, curl, shopify, php-curl

I am trying to use Shopify's API to pull order information with PHP. This is my first time using PHP for requests and wanted to get some experience as I am new to PHP in general.

```
function order_status($url, $user, $pass){
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: *.*','Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

```
$response = order_status($url, $user, $pass);
$responseJSON = json_decode($response);

echo "\n" , $responseJSON , "\n";
```

This is what is output to the terminal.

```
{"orders":[{"id":2083102294069,"name":"1031"}]}
1
```

I used the gettype method to check what was being returned in $response and it was a bool. Sorry if this is an obvious mistake but why isn't the JSON data being returned as a string in the response variable? Also, what is printing out the correct JSON to the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

> **CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER**
>
> `TRUE` to return the transfer as a string of the return value of `curl_exec()` instead of outputting it directly.

Then to check if things work, either

```
echo $response;
```

or

```
var_export( $responseJSON );
```